# LISP print function docstring

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, documentation

I am simply trying to print a LISP function's documentation string. The [LISP documentation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_docume.htm) is fairly ambiguous with regard to doctypes, so I am unsure as to how to do this. This is what I have so far:

```
(defun pr(x) "This is a docstring!" (+ x 1))
(documentation #'pr t)
```

I haven't found any concise answers on how to do this. Where is this wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's right.  You could also explicitly say `(documentation #'pr 'function)`.

However, as the Spec also notes:

> An implementation is permitted to discard documentation strings at any time for implementation-defined reasons.

So if you do not get the docstring, you may have to take a look at the documentation of the implementation you are using, the optimization settings, whether you are running interpreted or compiled etc.

Comment: How would I print just the function's name?

Comment: You can try the third value of `(function-lambda-expression some-fun)`, but the above caveats apply as well.

Comment: `(print (function-lambda-expression 'something))` yields `(LAMBDA (X) "hiii" (DECLARE (SYSTEM::IN-DEFUN SOMETHING))
 (BLOCK SOMETHING (+ X 1))) `, but I would just like to print `something`. How would I do that?

Comment: It's the third value.  `(nth-value 2 (function-lambda-expression #'something))`.